# Why won't this parent div respect the height (with padding) of its children?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a button/link that is centered in the content area of a webpage. Because it's a button, and not just a link, I'm adding some padding and background colour to it.

The link is centered horizontally, but the padding seems to expand outside the line-height of the parent element, causing it to overlap with previous/next elements. See: http://fths.convoke.info/what-can-i-do/

I tried creating a fiddle, but wasn't seeing the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/convoke/g9wu6ws9/

So what am I missing? Conversely, is there a better way to center a link like this? I don't like using `margin: auto` because it requires you specify the width. Ideally the width would be dynamic, so if the text on the button was longer or shorter, it would remain centered.

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` for the link, that will expand the line box of the div element.

Comment: Thank you! I actually tried using `display:block` to no avail. I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the answer I needed came from user @CBroe in the comments of my original question. He suggested using `display:inline-block` and that worked like a charm.

Still unsure as to why I was getting different results on the fiddle vs the actual website...